# I have a visual studio solution with a couple of projects but my build pipeline only publishes one project

Tags: visual-studio, pipelining, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a CI/CD but I'm only getting one artifact. The artifact that I'm getting is the client app (a Blazor application).
My solution structure is as follows:

-src

--API

--Core

--Domain

--UI

These are virtual maps in VS.
In the build stage, all projects get built.

This is the YAML:

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  package-version: '1.2.6'
  dotNetFramework: 'net6.0'
  dotNetVersion: '6.0.x'
  targetRuntime: 'linux-x64'
  azureSubscription: 'TestResources'

stages:
- stage: Build

  jobs:
    - job: build
     
      steps:
      - task: UseDotNet@2
        displayName: 'Use .NET 6 sdk'
        inputs:
          packageType: 'sdk'
          version: $(dotNetVersion)
          includePreviewVersions: true
              
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: Build solution
        inputs:
          command: 'build'
          projects: '**/*.sln'
          arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: Run unit tests
        inputs:
         command: 'test'
         projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
         arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- stage: Development
  displayName: 'Deploy to Dev'
  dependsOn: [ Build ]
  condition: succeeded()
  variables:
  - group: Apep

  jobs:
    - job:  DeployToDevelopment
      displayName: 'Deploy Development'
      variables:
        sqlFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/SQL/sqlscript.sql'
        
      steps:
         
      # Publish it as .NET 6 self-contained application for linux runtime
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          inputs:
            command: publish
            #publishWebProjects: false
            #arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --framework $(dotNetFramework) --runtime $(targetRuntime) --self-contained --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            zipAfterPublish: True
            projects: '**/*.sln'

        # Package the file and uploads them as an artifact of the build
        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          inputs:
            targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            artifact: 'drop'
            publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

I've tried targeting the projects parameter to target just one project but it keeps building my client application ( a Blazor application ).

Comment: project build order and flags are stored in the solution file. is the release build configuration set to build all projects or are any unchecked?

Comment: @FrankThomas all of them are checked.